# Can't see unread emails in some inboxes in thunderbird (osx mavericks)?

Tags: email, thunderbird, osx-mavericks

I have used Thunderbird for a while and I have had a constant problem of not being able to read some emails because I can't find them. I have tried restarting, removing the mail account and adding it again but the problem keeps reappearing.

I currently have 32 inboxes and I view them in a unified folder view. It's showing about 32700 messages at the moment. All inboxes are mostly IMAP (I believe a gmail and a yahoo account is POP3) and are mostly from custom installs on linux servers with a few from gmail, yahoo, live.

Looking at one inbox will show for example

```
someinboxname (2)
```

Which to means that there are two unread messages, however if I quickfilter for unread messages it will not show any messages which are unread. No matter how I sort the messages or scroll I cannot find the unread messages. I have no problem seeing most of the other new unread messages whether they are in this same inbox or in other inboxes.

I have also noticed that all inboxes emails will not show in the unified inbox. I am having to click on individual inboxes to read these emails.

I am usually the one with all the answers when it comes to computer problems but I have been unable to solve this problem. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? Maybe 32 inboxes is too much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was caused by emails being [ignored](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ignore-threads). See if the mails show up again after you check View -> Threads -> Ignore Threads.

Comment: That seems to have solved it :D

Comment: thanks men! 9 years after and your answer resolved my issue! The usability of Thunderbird around this is very weird. I was getting crazy with that, the counter showed 2 emails but all threads was marked read..

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Inbox showing (5) messages unread, but I couldn't see any unread message.

I fond the solution here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994807

- right-click on inbox
- Click properties
- Click on "Repair Folder"

That made thunderbird to sync again against the imap server and was able to see my unread mails.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, the other answers did not work in my case.

Comment: This worked, I also had to restart Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another site. Right click the unified Inbox, and choose the folders to include. Make sure all your inbox folders are checked. Worked for me with a Yahoo address.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it still does not seem to solve my issue.